# Bootstrap span button is became small not full when load ajax content into modal + Slow

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Anyone experience with slow ajax content load into modal and the button is became small and not full in the loaded content.

Example:

```html
**part of index.html**
<div id="floatcontainer" class="modal container hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-replace="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>

<a class="view" href="http://domain/data.html" style="text-decoration:none;">click to view</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.view').click(function(e){
                    $('body').modalmanager('loading');
                    //$('#floatcontainer').removeData(modal);
                    $('#floatcontainer').modal({remote : $(this).attr('href')});
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
</script>


**part of data.html**
<span class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-edit"><a href="edit.php" style="text-decoration:none; font-size:10px; color:black;">VIDEO</a></span>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Normally without load into modal**

[image]

Comment: anyone has same experience ?

Comment: Removing modalmanager is fixing slow content ajax load.
But not with ugly spanned button....
Will do some more test

Comment: Ugly spanned button fixed by fixing the <span /> to <span>